# grep + operator

Tags: grep, regular-expression

According to the grep manual:

```
  * The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
  + The preceding item will be matched one or more times.
```

Let's test it

```
echo 'agb' | grep 'a.*b' # returns agb
echo 'agb' | grep 'a.+b' # returns nothing
```

Why + did not match three gs? According to my knowledge 3 is more than 1.

Comment: The `+` quantifier has to be written as `\+` in BRE. So either `grep 'a.\+b'` or `grep -E 'a.+b'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever grep manual you're reading should also have a section explaining the different kinds of regular expressions (basic and extended). the `+` operator is not available in basic, only extended. To use extended regular expressions, you need the `-E` option.

Answer (score 5):

Much of what we think of as "regular expressions" are actually called *Extended Regular Expressions* (or EREs) in POSIX. But your `grep` call appears to be in *Basic Regular Expression* mode (or BRE, for short). BREs and EREs have a number of differences. One of these differences is that you have to escape metacharacters: `+` is a literal plus sign unless you escape it with a backslash. Your `grep` command appears to be in BRE mode, so try using `\+` instead of a plain `+`.

If you're being really strict about BRE versus ERE, then BREs don't actually support the `+` and `?` operations, though you can simulate them with `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}` constructs, respectively. Strict BREs don't support the `|` operator either, and I'm not sure how you simulate that in a BRE. However, unlike EREs, BREs support backreferences (which look a lot like they do in Perl, except that you have to escape the parens).

Some `grep` implementations (like GNU) support the `?`, `+`, and `|` operators in BRE mode, though you have to escape them like any other metacharacters: `\?`, `\+`, and `\|`. But no `grep` implementations that I'm aware of support backreferencing in ERE mode.

To force your `grep` to use ERE mode, you can use the `-E` option to `grep`, or you can call it as `egrep` instead.

Comment: GNU `grep -E` supports backreferences which you can verify with `echo aa | grep -E '(.)\1'`.